# Simplifying Factorials in Mathematical Induction

Tags: induction, factorial

I'm trying to understand an example for proof by mathematical induction from ["Book of Proof (PDF)"](http://www.people.vcu.edu/%7Erhammack/BookOfProof/Induction.pdf) (pg 158). I understand the basis step, but I'm not following the simplification in the inductive step, which I've copied below.

> Suppose $\sum_{i=0}^{k}i.i!=(k+1)!-1$. Then:
>
> $\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}i.i!=(\sum_{i=0}^{k}i.i!)+(k+1)(k+1)!$
>
> = $((k+1)!-1)+(k+1)(k+1)!$
>
> = $(k+1)!+(k+1)(k+1)!-1$
>
> = $(1+(k+1))(k+1)!-1$
>
> = $(k+2)(k+1)!-1$
>
> = $(k+2)!-1$
>
> = $((k+1)+1)!-1$

From lines 3 to 4 and from 5 to 6 it looks like $(k+1)!$ simplifies to $1$, but how?

Comment: They took first $(k+1)!$ in common like $xy+x=(y+1)x$ and then $(k+1)!(k+2)=(k+2)!$ like $3!\cdot 4 = 4!$

Comment: In line 3, let's substitute $x$ for $(k+1)!$. Then we have $x+(k+1)x-1$. Factor out the $x$ from the first two terms, giving $x[1+(k+1)]-1$.

Comment: And from line $5$ to line $6$ is just observing that $(n+1)n!=(n+1)!$, here with $n=k+1$.

Comment: Oh I see now! You can factor out (k+1)! like a variable, and (k+1)(k+2) are be consecutive integers. That makes perfect sense now, thank you! What do I do when a comment answer my question?

Comment: @kas you could now write an answer yourself which could include a fuller answer. You can then accept your answer and the community would be happy as its clear you've learnt something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\sum_{i=0}^{k}i.i!=(k+1)!-1$. Then:

$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}i.i!=(\sum_{i=0}^{k}i.i!)+(k+1)(k+1)!$

$((k+1)!-1)+(k+1)(k+1)!$

$(k+1)!+(k+1)(k+1)!-1$

*Factor out $(k+1)!$* to get $(1+(k+1))(k+1)!-1$

$(k+2)(k+1)!-1$

Since *(k+2)(k+1)! = (k+2), !*$(k+2)!-1$

$((k+1)+1)!-1$